# Symfony app > content of deploy:migrate task not executed

Tags: continuous-deployment, capistrano3, symfony-3.3

Can't execute the content ef deploy:migrate task.

`cap staging deploy:migrate` doesn't execute `doctrine:schema:update` symfony command. Instead, the response from task execution is empty.

```
lock "~> 3.11.0"

set :application, "some app"
set :repo_url, "...*.git"

set :stages, ["staging", "production"]
set :default_stage, "staging"

set :symfony_console_path, "bin/console"

set :linked_files, ["app/config/parameters.yml", "app/config/parameters_staging.yml"]
set :linked_dirs, ["app/logs", "vendor", "web/vendor", "web/assets", "web/uploads/user_data"]

set :model_manager, "doctrine"

set :format, :pretty
set :log_level, :debug
set :keep_releases, 3

after 'deploy:updated', 'symfony:assets:install'
after 'deploy:updated', 'deploy:migrate'

namespace :deploy do
    task :migrate do
      on roles(:db) do
         invoke 'symfony:console', 'doctrine:schema:update', '--force', '--env=staging'
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to put additional parameter `'--env=staging'`.